# Redirect to User_dashboard page after login based on user role with Spring Security Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have 2  roles {ADMIN, USER}. Once user login it should redirect to user_dashboard.html page, but it showing error. I am sharing POM.XML; MyCongig.java; UserController.java; user-dashboard.html and errorimage that I get after login. It would be a great help, if someone can help me as this is my first java/spring Boot project. Thanks in advance.

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.smart</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartcontactmanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>smartcontactmanager</name>
    <description>Smart Contact Manager Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Validation use this dependency-->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
            <!-- Password Dependency-->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.passay/passay -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.passay/passay -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**MyConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpel();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.getUserDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
        
    }
    
    //Configure method
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/signin")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/dologin")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/index").and().csrf().disable();
        //http.csrf().disable();
        
    }
    
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.smart.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String dashboard(Model model, Principal principal) {
        
        String userName = principal.getName();
        System.out.println("UserName "+userName);
        return "user_dashboard";
    }
}
```

**user_dashboard.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>USer Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome,  you are normal user</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[Errorimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEPtP.jpg)

Comment: Could you add any stacktraces error logs you see?

Answer (score 0):

Add this is in your MyConfig.java(you have to hasAnyRole for admin same

.hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN"))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).